# ActiveModel validate custom setter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activemodel

Say I have a custom setter on an activemodel model DateRange, to automatically set a DateTime attribute if a string is entered. It looks like this

```
  def from=(value)
    @from = value.to_date
  end
```

Now this does work if you enter a valid date string, but if you enter an invalid date, it stalls my application. How can I cancel assignment so that the application will move on and the DateRange fails validation later on in my controller?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: if i enter an invalid date, but in correct format, eg '13/13/2010', i get an ArgumentError (invalid date), but if i enter a malicious string eg 'not a date' i get NoMethodError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def from=(value)
  begin
    @from = value.to_date
  rescue ArgumentError, NoMethodError
    errors.add(:from, "is not a valid date")
  end
end
```

Probably a better way to do it but that should work

Comment: Problem with this is that doesn't prevent the attribute from being saved (with a `from` attribute as it was previously). For that I've found you need to encapsulate this logic inside a validator: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9676246/1755300

Comment: This solution is NOT correct. Calling `valid?` would completely ignore the added error and the model can be created/updated.

Comment: This will not work because `valid?` will [clean](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.3.2/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L336) `errors` before performing actual validation callbacks

Answer (score 2):

You would generally want to rescue/handle any problem in your setter.

```
def from=(value)
  @from = Date.parse(value)
rescue ArgumentError
  nil
end
```

Then let your normal date validations handle the nil value later.

I wouldn't add to your errors in the setter as it should not need to know about your validations and vice versa.

Comment: Wouldn't that be confusing to a user though as it would say it can't be blank (assuming validating presence) even though they input something?

Answer (score 1):

As @jordelver says, there is no point in adding validation errors except during validation.  However, you can save the error in a virtual attribute and check for it during validation.

```
validate :no_bad_dates
attr_accessor :bad_date_error

def from=(value)
  @from = Date.parse(value)
rescue ArgumentError => ex
  self.bad_date_error = ex
end

def no_bad_dates()
  errors.add(:from, bad_date_error.message) if bad_date_error
end
```

Comment: Note that `bad_date_error` does not need to be publicly accessible.  Implemented here as `attr_accessor` to simplify the story.